# Using $watch on an AngularJS service function defined as an ES6 class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using ES6 with AngularJS and am following [this guide](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/06/using-angular-1-dot-x-with-es6-and-webpack/). It recommends defining services as classes.

In a service definition I'm injecting the $cookieStore service and attaching it to the class like this:

```
export default class Authentication {
  constructor($cookieStore) {
    this.$cookieStore = $cookieStore;
  }

  setAuthenticatedAccount(account) {
    this.$cookieStore.put(JSON.stringify(account), 'authenticatedAccount');
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    return !!this.$cookieStore.get('authenticatedAccount');
  }
}
```

I want to update my navbar to reflect whether or not the user is logged in, which I'm doing with `$watch`:

```
var NavbarController = function($location, $scope, Authentication) {
    $scope.$watch(Authentication.isAuthenticated, () => {
        $scope.isAuthenticated = Authentication.isAuthenticated();
        $scope.currentUser = Authentication.getAuthenticatedAccount();
    });
}
```

This gives the following error:

`Cannot read property '$cookieStore' of undefined`.

Comment: How do you register the service? Your example only shows the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when you don't inject proper dependencies in your controller.

Just make sure that `$cookieStore` is propertly injected in your angular controller

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$cookieStore', function ($scope, $cookieStore) {
...
...
```

> *point to note*
>   The $cookieStore service is deprecated. Please use the $cookies service instead.